# Permalink broken for pages after adding rewrite rule

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

After adding these rewrite rules:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

The permalinks for pages do not longer work. I get a "not found" template everytime I try to access a page. Posts, home, and archives do work.

I added that rewrite rule because I want to be able to access users' archives without the author base tag like this:

```
http://sitename.com/authorname
```

Comment: Rewrite rule's sequence is the most important.. Pls check it out once...

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please elaborate more on your answer? Thanks